# Block files download from Amazon S3 without compromising Amazon Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-athena

I created this policy below to prevent users from downloading files in a specific Amazon S3 bucket, but they were also unable to run a query in Amazon Athena, getting a "Permission denied on S3 path: ..." error. Once I removed the policy, they were immediately able to run the query again. On the other hand, they can read a file in EMR Notebooks (PySpark), which is desirable.

How can I block files from being downloaded without compromising Athena's usage?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to explicitly deny users downloading from this bucket? Why don't you just remove the relevant S3 permission from those users so that they don't have permission in the first place?

Comment: Some user groups have full access to S3, so I'd have to add each permission but `s3:GetObject`, and this would probably use many characters, possibly reaching the limit. Although it might be a better way to handle it, for being more restrictive over time (new permissions might appear), the users would still not be able to run a query data in Athena since I can't add `s3:GetObject`, right?

Comment: According to the [Access to Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/s3-permissions.html) docs, "users must have permission to access Amazon S3 buckets in order to query them with Athena." One option might be to deny access unless [aws:CalledVia](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-calledvia) indicates Athena (aka athena.amazonaws.com).

Comment: I set a condition when `aws:CalledVia` `StringNotEquals` `athena.amazonaws.com` and it works, thank you! Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge here is in how Athena works. According to the [Access to Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/s3-permissions.html) docs:

> users must have permission to access Amazon S3 buckets in order to query them with Athena.

When users interact with Athena, their permissions pass through Athena to determine what Athena can access. So the user fundamentally needs to have GetObject permission in order for Athena to be able to read the objects.

That said, one option would be to modify your S3 bucket policy to deny access if the client is not actually Athena. You can do that using [aws:CalledVia](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-calledvia) which is present and indicates `athena.amazonaws.com` when Athena makes requests on behalf of the IAM user (or role). For example as follows:

```
"Condition": {
    "StringNotEquals": {"aws:CalledVia": "athena.amazonaws.com"}
}
```